# How do nested loops in Java work?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am new to Java programming and trying to learn the basics of coding. I want to know how this snippet of code works?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        System.out.print((i * j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I will be really thankful if the programming sherlocks present here can explain me the logic.

Comment: In each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will be executed. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Is TheNewCodingKing not able to solve his homework ?

Comment: I have tried it. According to the logic coming to my mind the output should be  1 4 9 16 25 30 35 40 45 50... means till i=5 the outer loop will get executed then it will stop there and taking i=5, inner loop will continue the multiplication till j=10. Is this right?

Comment: Besides just running it, trace the code execution on paper. There is no magic.

Comment: @JavaLearner The inner loop isn't incrementing one-for-one with the outer loop, it's running in its entirety (from 1–10) each time the outer loop is ran.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is very generic.

Comment: yes got it finally... We need to execute outer loop's iterations one by one first(embedding in it the inner loop's iterations) as experts have explained here. Thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will do...

```
1*1 1*2 1*3 till it gets to 1*10, then on a new line
2*1 2*2 2*3 and it will go to all the way to 
.
.
5*10
```

So it will print out `1 2 3 4 5 ...` till 10, then do a new line.  Output below.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 
4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {   // outer loop iterates 5 times.
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {  // for each iteration of outer loop, 
                                     // inner loop iterates 10 times
        System.out.print((i * j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

First iteration of outer loop (10 iterations of inner loop)

```
i = 1, j = 1
i = 1, j = 2
...
i = 1, j = 10
```

Second iteration of outer loop (10 iterations of inner loop)

```
i = 2, j = 1
i = 2, j = 2
...
i = 2, j = 10
```

...

Last iteration of outer loop (10 iterations of inner loop)

```
i = 5, j = 1
i = 5, j = 2
...
i = 5, j = 10
```

Comment: Nicely explained... :) Thanks for the help..!!

Answer (score 1):

because of `trying to learn the basics of coding`, sharing this.

Once you come inside the loop (i), you faced second loop (j).

Now second loop will finish first, so for each i, j will be 1-10.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll work from te outside to the inside: every time the 'top' loop will run, that is, 5 times, it will execute the code between the brackets.

In there, there is another loop, using j as index, which will run 10 times. So when we run the  upper loop 5 times, and time it executes another loop 10 times, we'll get that this run 50 times. So 50 times, this will print out the product of i and j.

After each 10 loops of the 'j'-loop, it will print out a new line.

Answer (score 0):

the inner loop will be executed 10 times for each iteration of the outer loop so this inner loop will get executed for 50 times in this program.

when `i =1` the control enters the outer loop and control flows to the inner loop,
now `j=1` and it satisfies the condition `j<=10` so will enter the inner loop

now this will print

```
1
```

then `j` will get incremented and `j` will be 2 still satisfying the condition `j<=10`
and prints

```
2
```

now the line looks like

```
1 2
```

this goes on till `j<=10` is false that is when `j` is `11` the inner loop will stop executing
and control flows to the next print statement that prints a new line

then `i` gets incremented to `2` and the same thing happens till `i <=5` is false that is when
`i` becomes `6` the loop stops.

Comment: @JavaLearner : glad i was of help :)