# Indexing in java arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I had to write a method in Java, where having in input an array `a` of numbers and a number `x` returns an array of elements which follows the last occurrence of `x` in `a`.

For example with input `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` and `x=6` the method must return `{7,8,9}` meanwhile with `{4,1,4,2}` and `x=4` the method must return `{2}` and if the `x` is not in `a` then it must return empty array `{}` (or array with 0 length)

so I got this answer:

```
int idx = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
    if (s[i] == x)
        idx = i;
}

/* After you found this index, create a new array starting 
 * from this element. It can be done with a second (not nested) for loop, or you can
 * use Arrays.copyOfRange()
 */

//make sure idx != -1
int[] t = new int[s.length - idx - 1];
for (int i = idx + 1; i < s.length; i++)
    t[i - idx - 1] = s[i];
```

which was very helpful but I could not understand why this works:(EDITED; Ok now I understand why this works but even if in my opinion the combined for loop ideea was more less complicated to read)

```
t[i - idx - 1] = s[i];
```

and this doesn't:

```
int[] t = new int[a.length - indx - 1];
for (int j = indx + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        t[i]=a[j];
    }
}
return t;
```

EDITED :
To clarify this is all the code

```
int[] dopoX(int[] a, int x) {
    int n = a.length;
    int[] c = new int[0];
    int indx = 0;
    int nrx = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[j] == x)
            nrx++;
        if (a[j] == x)
            indx=j;
    }
    if (nrx == 0)
        return c;   
    int[] t = new int[n - indx - 1];
    for (int j = indx + 1; j < n; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            t[i] = a[j]; /* it returns just 1 number of a[] like t{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2} which is 
                            not correct */          
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because the last snippet doesn't use `idx` in any way.

Comment: Do you want to fill an array t with one value of s[i]?

Comment: How are you relating i and j? i should change as to more further in the array,

Comment: I presume you mean something like `t[j] = s[j + idx + 1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you want to copy all the remaining values, and create an array of index `t`. Thus you need to start with `i=0`. You can however perform a *shift-operation*: increase `i` somewhere, and when you use it, shift it back, so:

```
for (int i = idx+1; i < s.length; i++)
    t[i-idx-1] = s[i];
```

is equvalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
    t[i] = s[i+idx+1];
```

(which would have been more readable as well)

---

**About your second question:**

here you use a [nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996813/how-do-nested-loops-in-java-work): the second `for` loop will be repeated each iteration of the first one.

The result is thus that in the second `for`-loop, `j` is always fixed, with input `{1,2,...,9}` and `6` in the first iteration, you would fill your array with `7`s, next `8`s and finally `9`s.

You can however use a *combined `for` loop*:

```
int []t=new int[n-indx-1];
//       /-- grouped initializers      /-- grouped increments
//       |                             |
for(int i=0, j= indx+1; i < t.length; i++, j++){
    t[i]=a[j];
}
return t;
```

Comment: Ok so I understood the idea of nested loop for every i=1 j would go j=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc

then again i=2 j=1,2,3,4,5,6 ; and i guess even losing the brackets its still nested cause for me seem more easy reading i=0 i++ with t[i] than t[i-index-1] , the logic of it .dont know if I got myself understood

Comment: Yes. So that means in the second `for` loop, you fill your array with the same number. The result is that in the end, `t` is filled with the values of the last element of `a`. Thus in this case `{9,9,9}`.

Comment: yea because it gets the last value where the counter stops right?

ok so for a nested for loop I understand now the t[i] will forever be the last a[j] where j stops cool

Comment: @SerbanCosmin: indeed: it keeps overriding the values until it reaches the end.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of code finds the last index of x inside of the array.

The second line uses the built-in function of Arrays to copy a range from an array to a new copy.

And we copy from the values after the last x until lenght of array a.

The first line could be rewritten to search from the end and backwards in the array with a break. This will give a performance boost but makes the code less easy to read.

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) if(a[i]==x) idx=i;

int[] b = Arrays.copyRangeTo(a, idx+1, a.length);
```

Comment: A less verbose solution indeed

Comment: The question was "why does X work, and Y not work". An answer that has no explanation of anything is not an answer to the question, regardless of whether or not the code in it actually works.

Comment: Sorry wrote the answer while the question was formulated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain, what you're doing here and why it's an improvement over the OPs code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Hope my explanation makes my answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you take the case where `a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` and `x = 6`.
Running this:

```
int idx = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
if (s[i] == x) idx = i;
}
```

You got `idx = 5` as `s[5] == x`.

Now we want to copy the array after the last instance of `x` into a new array `t[]`.

Obviously, you have to start from the index `idx + 1` as `idx` contained the last occurance of `x`.

Hence, this code:

```
int[] t = new int[s.length - idx - 1];
for (int i = idx+1; i < s.length; i++)
    t[i-idx-1] = s[i];
```

What do you do here?

You construct a new array `t[]` having length `s.length - idx - 1`, in our case `s.length = 9` and `idx = 5` hence, we have the `s.length - idx - 1` as `3` and we can check that is the number of elements after `x = 6`.

Now, we start the iterator `i` from `idx + 1` (Reason explained above) to `s.length`

We have `t[i - idx - 1]` because when `i = idx + 1`, `i - idx - 1 = 0`. Hence as `i` increases, your `i - idx - 1` also increases.

Hope it was convincing. Please comment if you still have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int j=0;
int i=idx+1;
while (j<t.length) {
    t[j] = s[i];
    j++;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `While` loops are better not used for things that can be done with `for` loops, as the chance of creating an *infinite loop* is larger...

Comment: The question was "why does X work, and Y not work".  An answer that just says "try this" and has no explanation of anything is not an answer to the question, regardless of whether or not the code in it actually works.