# How can I see each permutation of `FormatStyle` for a localized `DateTimeFormatter` in Java?

Tags: java, localization, datetime-format, java-time

I cannot find documentation about the particular behavior of [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) set for the date portion and time portion of a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) when [automatically localizing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-):

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle dateStyle, FormatStyle timeStyle)
```

Is there some way to know the possible variations of strings generated for any particular `Locale`?

Answer (score 1):

## Loop all possible values

Yes, you can easily loop through the possible [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) values.

### `EnumSet`

That class is an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), providing several pre-defined objects. You can get a collection of those objects by calling [`EnumSet.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf-java.lang.Class-).

```
EnumSet< FormatStyle > styles = EnumSet.allOf( FormatStyle.class ) ;
```

### Nested loops

So we need a pair of [nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19996933/642706): one outer loop using each possible style for the date portion, and one inner loop using each possible style for the time-of-day portion.

For each combination of date-style and time-style, we instantiate a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for the specific [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( );
System.out.println( "---|  " + zdt + "  |-------------" );

Locale locale = Locale.US;
for ( FormatStyle styleDate : EnumSet.allOf( FormatStyle.class ) )
{
    for ( FormatStyle styleTime : EnumSet.allOf( FormatStyle.class ) )
    {
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( styleDate , styleTime ).withLocale( locale );
        String output = zdt.format( f );
        int padSpacesOutTo = 17 ;  // The longest possible value is "MEDIUM | MEDIUM", with a length of 15 characters.
        String styles = styleDate + " | " + styleTime ;
        String stylesLabel  = String.format("%1$-" + padSpacesOutTo + "s", styles ) ;
        System.out.println( stylesLabel + output   );
    }
}
```

Output for [`Locale.US`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US).

```
---|  2017-09-11T13:15:02.193544-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]  |-------------
FULL | FULL      Monday, September 11, 2017 at 1:15:02 PM Pacific Daylight Time
FULL | LONG      Monday, September 11, 2017 at 1:15:02 PM PDT
FULL | MEDIUM    Monday, September 11, 2017, 1:15:02 PM
FULL | SHORT     Monday, September 11, 2017, 1:15 PM
LONG | FULL      September 11, 2017 at 1:15:02 PM Pacific Daylight Time
LONG | LONG      September 11, 2017 at 1:15:02 PM PDT
LONG | MEDIUM    September 11, 2017, 1:15:02 PM
LONG | SHORT     September 11, 2017, 1:15 PM
MEDIUM | FULL    Sep 11, 2017, 1:15:02 PM Pacific Daylight Time
MEDIUM | LONG    Sep 11, 2017, 1:15:02 PM PDT
MEDIUM | MEDIUM  Sep 11, 2017, 1:15:02 PM
MEDIUM | SHORT   Sep 11, 2017, 1:15 PM
SHORT | FULL     9/11/17, 1:15:02 PM Pacific Daylight Time
SHORT | LONG     9/11/17, 1:15:02 PM PDT
SHORT | MEDIUM   9/11/17, 1:15:02 PM
SHORT | SHORT    9/11/17, 1:15 PM
```

Again, using [`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH).

```
---|  2017-09-11T13:32:00.434143-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]  |-------------
FULL | FULL      lundi 11 septembre 2017 à 13:32:00 heure avancée du Pacifique
FULL | LONG      lundi 11 septembre 2017 à 13:32:00 HAP
FULL | MEDIUM    lundi 11 septembre 2017 13:32:00
FULL | SHORT     lundi 11 septembre 2017 13:32
LONG | FULL      11 septembre 2017 à 13:32:00 heure avancée du Pacifique
LONG | LONG      11 septembre 2017 à 13:32:00 HAP
LONG | MEDIUM    11 septembre 2017 13:32:00
LONG | SHORT     11 septembre 2017 13:32
MEDIUM | FULL    11 sept. 2017 13:32:00 heure avancée du Pacifique
MEDIUM | LONG    11 sept. 2017 13:32:00 HAP
MEDIUM | MEDIUM  11 sept. 2017 13:32:00
MEDIUM | SHORT   11 sept. 2017 13:32
SHORT | FULL     17-09-11 13:32:00 heure avancée du Pacifique
SHORT | LONG     17-09-11 13:32:00 HAP
SHORT | MEDIUM   17-09-11 13:32:00
SHORT | SHORT    17-09-11 13:32
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/tXbmvz). Caveat: **IdeOne uses only `Locale.US`** and ignores all others locales.

Left to the reader as an execise: Go crazy and add a third loop to the outside of the nest, for each `Locale` in the array returned from [`Locale.getAvailableLocales()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales--). … Or look at [the Answer by Hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46164494/642706).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know all the results of **generated** strings (the final result of `format` method), then [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163949/7605325) covers it well. I'd just add another external loop through all the locales, because different locales also can have different format styles.

If you want to know the **patterns**, though, you can use the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#getLocalizedDateTimePattern-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.chrono.Chronology-java.util.Locale-) within the same nested loops. I also used `values()` method instead of `EnumSet` (not sure if it makes difference):

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    System.out.println("--|For locale " + locale + "|-------");
    for (FormatStyle styleDate : FormatStyle.values()) {
        for (FormatStyle styleTime : FormatStyle.values()) {
            String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(styleDate, styleTime, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
            int padSpacesOutTo = 17;
            String styles = styleDate + " | " + styleTime;
            String stylesLabel = String.format("%1$-" + padSpacesOutTo + "s", styles);
            System.out.println(stylesLabel + pattern);
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be (depending on all the available locales in your JVM) something like this:

```
--|For locale ar_AE|-------
FULL | FULL      dd MMMM, yyyy z hh:mm:ss a
FULL | LONG      dd MMMM, yyyy z hh:mm:ss a
FULL | MEDIUM    dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss a
FULL | SHORT     dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm a
LONG | FULL      dd MMMM, yyyy z hh:mm:ss a
LONG | LONG      dd MMMM, yyyy z hh:mm:ss a
LONG | MEDIUM    dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss a
LONG | SHORT     dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm a
MEDIUM | FULL    dd/MM/yyyy z hh:mm:ss a
MEDIUM | LONG    dd/MM/yyyy z hh:mm:ss a
MEDIUM | MEDIUM  dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a
MEDIUM | SHORT   dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a
SHORT | FULL     dd/MM/yy z hh:mm:ss a
SHORT | LONG     dd/MM/yy z hh:mm:ss a
SHORT | MEDIUM   dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss a
SHORT | SHORT    dd/MM/yy hh:mm a
--|For locale ar_JO|-------
FULL | FULL      dd MMMM, yyyy z hh:mm:ss a
FULL | LONG      dd MMMM, yyyy z hh:mm:ss a
FULL | MEDIUM    dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss a
... lots of output
```